# Adding an answer to a question that already has an accepted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I sometimes find that a better answer can be provided to a question answered a few years earlier.  But the user who posted the question is probably long gone.

Is there a point in adding an answer when there is already an accepted answer to a question?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is! If you have another way to answer the question posed, that you think has some merits, please post it. The answers are not just for the user who posted the question. Think of all the people who will be looking for that question later (depending on the question, there may be hundreds or thousands of them... or hundreds *of* thousands).

For example, the question [How long do I have to finish a keg once it's been tapped?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/how-long-do-i-have-to-finish-a-keg-once-its-been-tapped) has been viewed by over 128000 people by now. The user who posted it hasn't been around much (has not been seen for a few months, at least), but this is no longer about him: the important thing is that the question and its answers made the Internet a little bit better.